# Netbeans SOAP response Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence

Tags: soap, netbeans, utf-8, response

So, I made a simple web service in Netbeans 7.2.1, which perfectly works with non UTF-8 char(s), while, even if a single UTF-8 char exists in the database table needed by a web service, after invoking it, i get this message :

SOAP Response
Service invocation threw an exception with message : com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.; Refer to the server log for more details.

If I replace UTF8 char(s) in a database table, web service works fine.

Just to mention, I use netbeans, jtds 1.3 ms sql server driver, and glassfish 3.1.2.2

---

UPDATE : I think, I managed somehow to reslove this issue :

1. Go to : %GF_Install_dir%\glassfish_3_version\glassfish\domains\domain1\config
2. Open domain.xml
3. Find the line beginning with :
   < java-config .../>

   ```
                            < jvm-options> ... />
   ```

   .. and add new line like this :
   < jvm-options>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8< /jvm-options>
4. Restart GF server.

Comment: I can confirm - in my case `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` solves this problem.